# NullpointerException in Struts2 application when running with multiple applications in tomcat

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, struts2

In my Struts2 application accessing jsp values using object throwing NullPointerException.

I have follwing code in jsp

```
<s:textfield name="controlObj.newname"  onclick="removeError();"/>
```

i have a bean for this `controlObj` in Struts2 Action class

```
private ControlForm controlObj;

public ControlForm getControlObj() {
    return controlObj;
}
public void setControlObj(ControlForm controlObj) {
    this.controlObj= controlObj;
}
```

but when i access this `newname` property in action java file it throws NullpointerException, But in ControlForm class i have initiatilized newname

```
public ControlForm () {
       newname ="Update name here...";
    }
```

Is there any problem in coding syantax i'm using??? because i can get the values if the properties are defined directly in Action class like

```
private String variable_name;
```

i get the nullPointerException only for the variables of type `Object.property` !!!

**Update:**

1. In Firebug tool i can see the value for `controlObj.newname` passed
   with form submit.
2. I'm not getting any error when i run this
   application as standalone in tomcat,"controlObj.newname" returns
   value. if throws null only when anyother struts2 application running
   with this application in Tomcat

Comment: add the structure of ControlForm

Comment: Are you actually instantiating an instance of `HandoutForm` (I assume this extends or implements `ControlForm`) and referencing it in the `controlObj` field?

Comment: Where are you deploying the S2 libraries?

Comment: struts2-core-2.0.11 in application lib folders

Answer (score 3):

The NullPointerException you are getting is not due to the newname not being initialised, but due to controlObj not being initialised. When Struts uses getControlObj() to get the controlObj, null is returned, since controlObj has not been initialised and then getNewname() on this null object throws a NullPointerException. This should be solved if you initialised controlObj properly in your action.

Comment: i forget to include, controlObj also initialized in action file.and in jsp file 'controlObj.newname'  display the value what i put in constructor